# Is there a concept of "default branch" in vanilla git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

While there is a concept of "default branch name" in git, I do not see any mention of "default branch" in [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) or [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).

However, I do see mentions of "default branch" in git hosting platforms such as [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch) and [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/default.html#change-the-default-branch-name-for-a-project).

So, is there a concept of "default branch" in vanilla git? Or is it only a concept used by git hosting platforms?

Comment: No, default branch on git is **master**

Comment: @MickaelB. the default branch on git indeed **was** master. This triggers some issues (https://git.github.io/rev_news/2020/07/29/edition-65/) and now, the default branch name is a parameter. And the default of this parameter is master.

Answer (score 4):

In git's model, there are no special "server" or "central" repositories. When you clone a repository, then git will by default check out whatever branch is checked out on that other repository. More specifically, it will copy the `.git/HEAD` file from the other repository into the new clone.

At the most basic, a git server (including hosting platforms such as Github and GitLab) is just what git calls a "bare repository", which contains all the files which would normally be in the `.git` directory, but no working copy. See [the manual for `git clone --bare`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---bare) and ["Git on the Server" in the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).

That means the repository still has a file called `HEAD` which contains a reference to the "current" branch. When you perform a clone from the server, that is the reference copied to your new `.git/HEAD`. As such, it acts as the "default branch" for new clones, but in git's terminology it is actually the "current" branch.

Management UIs commonly also use this as a convenient way to set the default branch shown in the file browser, the default target for pull/merge requests, etc.

Comment: The question was about 'vanilla' git. This response miss the target.

Comment: @Orace Everything in this answer except the last sentence **is** about "vanilla" git. Bare repositories are an entirely native concept, and documented as a way of sharing code.

Comment: @Orace I've updated the answer to make clearer that git doesn't call this a "default branch", it's just the effect of some other decisions. Does it feel "on target" to you now?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing seems to be the `init.defaultBranch` [config entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-initdefaultBranch).

It allows to set which name will be used at `git init` for the first commit/branch. (see also [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---initial-branchltbranch-namegt))

The default value for this parameter is **master**.

Comment: plus the `HEAD` reference of a remote repo which is checked out by default when you `git clone`

Comment: init.defaultBranch would set the "default branch name" already mentioned in the question, and is unrelated to the concept of "default branch" used by hosting services.